# ffmpeg not found when running python google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

According to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages) all cloud function environments have ffmpeg.

However, running this code:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("ffmpeg")
```

... on a `python310` env fails with this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'
```

Later Edit:

I ran this code in a `python310` cloud function:

```py
import subprocess

def find_ffmpeg(request):
  cmd = ['find', '/', '-name','"ffmpeg"']
  ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)   
  out, err = ffmpeg.communicate()
  return out
```

yeah, no result.

Comment: Is the ffmpeg command in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @JohnGordon it's a cloud function, I don't control its environment. When they say those packages are installed, I assume they're also linked to some `/usr/bin` path

Comment: theoretically `ffmpeg` should be installed and accessible without full path but better check in system `/full/lpath/to/ffmpeg` and use this path in `subprocess`.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I downgraded to python37 runtime and now I DO have access to ffmpeg. Perhaps the latest runtime environment (erroneously for sure) doesn't have ffmpeg installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to a [current issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242685280), ffmpeg is currently not available within the python310 runtime.
Your best bet is most likely to use the python39 runtime until the issue gets resolved.